# Create a DataFrame with an array data for every value in a date range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am hoping to develop a data frame which has the rows formed of the values from an array, which is repeated for every date in a series, the dates therefore form the date range.

So the two arrays are as below, and infected is the values for the rows in every column and date_range is every column.

```
infected = array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
date_range = pd.date_range(start="2020-05-07",end="2020-05-30")
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

This hope fully would look like:

```
2020-05-07  2020-05-08 etc
1           1
1           1
1           1
1           1
1           1
1           1
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It's a convention to do `import numpy as np`, so your array should become `np.array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
pd.DataFrame({d: infected for d in date_range})
```

Comment: Please accomodate this answer in your previous post. No point in creating multiple posts by the same person.